# How do I put child nodes into their own parent node?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parent-child, xmldocument

I have the following XML input:

```
<init>
   <options>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
   </options>
</init>
```

I would like to transform this into the following output XML:

```
<init>
    <options>
       <option>1</option>
    </options>
    <options>
       <option>2</option>
    </options>
    <options>
       <option>3</option>
    </options>
</init>
```

So instead of one `<options>` tag, I want to create multiple `<options>` tags based on the amount of child nodes within the input XML.

I'm using XmlDocument in C# .NET.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the format exactly you have provided

```
var xmlStr = @"<init>
                  <options>
                     <option>1</option>
                     <option>2</option>
                     <option>3</option>
                  </options>
               </init>";
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);

        var resultDoc = new XmlDocument();
        resultDoc.LoadXml("<init></init>");
        XmlElement elem;

        foreach (XmlElement node in xmlDoc.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
        {
            elem = resultDoc.CreateElement("options");
            resultDoc.FirstChild.AppendChild(elem);

            elem = resultDoc.CreateElement("option");
            elem.InnerText = node.InnerText;
            resultDoc.FirstChild.LastChild.AppendChild(elem);
        }

Console.WriteLine(resultDoc.InnerXml);
```

Edit:
Instead of creating new XmlDocument, you can use the same document and reorder your elements. I hope this is what you meant.

```
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);

xmlDoc.FirstChild.InnerXml = string.Join("", 
    xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//option")
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Select(n => n.OuterXml));

XmlElement elem;
foreach (XmlElement node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//init//option"))
{
    xmlDoc.FirstChild.RemoveChild(node);
    elem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("options");
    elem.AppendChild(node);
    xmlDoc.FirstChild.AppendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: Great! What if the input I provided is part of a bigger XML? Right now you are building it up from scratch in a second XmlDocument.

Comment: You can use the same document if you have larger XML files. Select all the <option> elements, remove the <options> element and start appending to the same document. E.g.

var child = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//option");
xmlDoc.FirstChild.RemoveChild(xmlDoc.FirstChild.FirstChild);

Comment: I basically need to have a parent element <options> around every <option> element. I don't get any further with your last comment

Comment: The Cast on a NodeList within the Xmldocument is not supported tho. I'm kinda new to this so I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: Have you added "using System.Linq;" in the class? You will need reference to System.Linq to make it work properly.

Comment: I have added System.Xml.Linq yes

Comment: Aah. I did using System.Xml.Linq, now it compiles

Comment: No "System.Xml.Linq", make it just "System.Linq"

Comment: It’s finished btw, there was another problem but everything works now. Thanks for the help!